# Powershell IIS Server Level Data

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-8

I can get site information but I can not for the life of me figure out how to get server information. So I am trying to get custom field information and I can retrieve each of the sites listed by running this code...

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty '/system.applicationHost/sites/site/logfile/customFields' -PSPath IIS:\ -Name collection
```

But this gives me each site. I need to be able to get the info for when I click on the actual server. Is there a way to gather this information? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try replacing ``-PSPath IIS:\`` with `-PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried that and I am still getting the same info. I could be wrong but I think it has something to do with the '/system.applicationHost/sites/site/logfile/customFields' portion of it since it is pointing to Sites/site. But looking here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/logfile/customfields/add I can't seem to find anything that points me to the server

Comment: What kind of server information you want to get? One server only can install one IIS, no too many IIS. You just need to check applicationhost.config file to get all information of IIS.

Comment: @BruceZhang when I run the above code I get the data I am looking for but it is for each of the sites. When I click on server in IIS Manager I need that server information which is similar data but just for the server instead of the data for each of the sites.

Comment: @BruceZhang the applicationhost.config file is what I was looking for thank you very much for all of your help